# Consider Non-Null value while performing groupBy operation using Spark-SQL

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this table below. I hope to group by the name and produce the final result, but instead of doing aggregation but sort of use value from one row to fill in the empty column in another row.

Please let me know if I can explain this better. Can someone please shed some light on this?. I need SQL statement to get required result.

Input:

```
    name          value_1            value_2
    -----------------------------------------
    prod1         code1               code11
    prod2         code2              
    prod3         code3 
    prod3                             code33
    prod4         code4
```

Expected output:

```
    name         value_1            value_2
   -------------------------------------------
    prod1         code1               code11
    prod2         code2              
    prod3         code3               code33 -- the two rows for prod3 in the table above are grouped together
    prod4         code4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the SQL version of answer posted by  @Robert Kossendey

```
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("tab")
   spark.sql("select name, first(value_1, true), first(value_2, true) from tab group by name")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `first()` with the `True` flag could do the trick, you would get the first value that is not null:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy('name').agg(F.first('value_1', True), F.first('value_2', True)).show()
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way of doing this with spark.sql ("...") but not api?